# .tar.gz file downloaded as HTML document, ASCII text

Tags: command-line, 16.10, tar, gzip

While going through the following instructions:

```
curl -O http://static.druid.io/artifacts/releases/druid-latest-bin.tar.gz
tar -xzf druid-latest-bin.tar.gz
cd druid-latest
```

I received the following error:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Then I tried:

```
file druid-latest-bin.tar.gz
```

and I get back:

```
HTML document, ASCII text
```

What should I do to download the file correctly (to be able to unzip)?

Comment: I think it should be `tar -zxf druid-latest-bin.tar.gz`

Comment: To me seems that your link does not exist, thats why you get HTML document, cause you've downloaded a `html` file.

Comment: @George Trying -zxf gives back the following:`tar (child): druid-latest-bin.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`

Comment: Then the link might not be valid

Comment: See if there is an error message in the `HTML` file: `less druid-latest-bin.tar.gz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is broken, use this command instead:

```
curl -O http://static.druid.io/artifacts/releases/druid-0.10.0-bin.tar.gz
tar -xzf druid-0.10.0-bin.tar.gz
cd druid-*
```

and follow other instructions.